# Firefox isn't allowing me to set a persistent cookie with FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, firefox, cookies, forms-authentication

I have code which validates a login form (with an option to "remember me") and, if valid, authenticate the user. I then set the forms auth cookie and redirect.

The auth cookie is set as follows, with the `persistent` argument being `true` if the user has selected "remember me".

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.UserObject.UserName, persistent);
Response.Redirect(url);
```

We've tested this in various browsers and generally all is well. However, in Firefox the `.ASPXFORMSAUTH` cookie is always a session cookie which expires when the browser is closed, even when the `persistent` argument above is `true`.

The version of Firefox I'm testing with is 55.0.3 (32 bit). Is this a known bug? Or is there some other reason Firefox might not be letting me set a persistent cookie? Could it be that it no longer accepts persistent cookies as part of a 302 redirect response?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1046134

Comment: This link didn't contain the precise solution, but it did point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a pointer from @gabriel-luci I found the solution. In the Firefox preferences (about:preferences#privacy) my browser had been set to use custom settings for History and was configured to keep cookies only until Firefox was closed. I don't remember changing this myself, but a check with colleagues suggests that the default is to keep cookies until they expire. So if you're getting the same issue, start with Firefox prefs.